# Is there any idiomatic way to add methods to object in Python?

Tags: javascript, python, idioms

As example I have to make calculator with some basic math operations:

```
class Power_calc():
    def calculate(self, exp):
        self.srt = exp.split(" ")
        self.x = float(self.srt[0])
        self.y = float(self.srt[2])
        operand = self.srt[1]
        if operand == '+':
            return self.summ(self.x, self.y)
        elif operand == "-":
            return self.minus(self.x, self.y)

    def summ(self, a, b):
        return a + b

    def minus(self, a, b):
        return a - b

calc1 = Power_calc()
print calc1.calculate("3.2 + 6.0")
```

Is there any way to group all calculator methods in dictionary like it could be done in Javascript (example below):

```
function powerCalculator() {
var methods = { //adding all methods here
    '+': function(a, b) {
        return a + b;
    },
    '-': function(a, b) {
        return a - b;
    }
};
this.calculate = function(expression) {
    var arr = expression.split(' '),
    a = +arr[0],
    b = +arr[2],
    operand = arr[1]
    return methods[operand](a, b);
}
```

Comment: You can do exactly the same thing in Python!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. Python functions are first-class objects, so you can store them in a dictionary just like you can in JavaScript.

If you want to define the functions in-line you can use lambdas:

```
methods = {
    '+': lambda a, b: a + b,
    # ...
}
```

or otherwise just reference external functions:

```
def plus(a, b): return a + b

methods = {
    '+': plus,
    # ...
}
```

Note that methods are just wrapped functions (storing the `self` reference); you can use `self.summ` and `self.minus` in your dictionary to store the bound methods:

```
class Power_calc():
    def calculate(self, exp):
        methods = {
            '+': self.summ,
            '-': self.minus,
        }

        self.srt = exp.split(" ")
        self.x = float(self.srt[0])
        self.y = float(self.srt[2])
        operand = self.srt[1]
        return methods[operand](self.x, self.y)

    def summ(self, a, b):
        return a + b

    def minus(self, a, b):
        return a - b
```

Easier still, you can use the [`operator` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) here for *predefined* operation functions:

```
import operator

methods = {
    '+': operator.add
    # ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing in JS isn't adding methods, it's just creating a mapping from names to functions, which you then use explicitly inside the `calculate` method. You can do exactly the same thing in Python (and with less boilerplate, to boot):

```
class PowerCalculator(object):
    methods = {
        '+': (lambda a, b: a + b),
        '-': (lambda a, b: a - b)
    }
    def calculate(self, expression):
        arr = expression.split(' ')
        a = float(arr[0])
        b = float(arr[2])
        op = arr[1] # note that this is the operator, not the operand
        return self.methods[op](a, b)
```

This isn't *exactly* the same as what you're doing in JS, but it's very close. In JS, you're creating a scope that has the `methods` variable defined in it, and then defining your prototype's `calculate` method as a closure within that scope. While you *could* do that in Python, you don't have to, because you have the `class` statement, which creates a scope specifically for defining methods and other class attributes in, so you can just define `methods` normally and access it as an attribute.

---

If you really want to define `summ` and `minus` as methods rather than as inline functions with `lambda`, you can. However, you may want them to be `@staticmethod`s—after all, they don't do anything with `self`.

---

If you really want them to be normal methods, you can even do that. But then what you have inside the dict are going to be unbound methods, which means you have to explicitly pass along the `self` to call them. Like this:

```
class PowerCalculator(object):
    def summ(self, a, b):
        return a + b

    def minus(self, a, b):
        return a - b

    methods = {
        '+': summ,
        '-': minus
    }

    def calculate(self, expression):
        arr = expression.split(' ')
        a = float(arr[0])
        b = float(arr[2])
        op = arr[1] # note that this is the operator, not the operand
        return self.methods[op](self, a, b)
```

But there's really no advantage to adding this extra complexity.

Comment: @NazarIlkiv: Well, it can be hard to get the wording right in cases like this. After all, those things are methods of the abstract calculator that you're representing with your class or prototype, even if they're represented by functions, not methods of that class or prototype…

Comment: Thanks for instructions!